# How can I use one Google Scholar account with two different university emails?

Tags: publications, university, email, google-scholar

I have a *[Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com)* account which is verified by an **university** account (*let's call it university "A"*), and my account on **scholar** has three articles in it.

But now, I got a second **university** account from another university (*I finished my studies in the first one, let's call the new university "B"*), which I used it to publish one article.

I was trying to add this other **university "B"** account to the same **google scholar** account, so that my **scholar** account would be **verified by two university** accounts and would **show all my four articles**, my attempt to do so failed because I couldn't be able to **add another verification email** to my **scholar** account.

*So, the question is: is there a way to do that?*

I need this because I can't use one university account for all four articles since one of them is published by using another university account.

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that, but more to the point, why would you need this? Whether you keep the verified email as-is or replace it, there is no issue with showing publications with affiliations that don't match the verified email domain.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is ... "you don't". There is no reason to, and Google Scholar doesn't directly provide that facility.

The usual practice is to update your university email address to indicate your current, verified affiliation. That will not normally lead to you losing any links to those articles that were published while you at the previous university.

So, just update your details to the new university, verify your account ... and all should be well.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, I'll try to do so and see what would happen.